# LINQ expression using a previously defined variable

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am trying to create a LINQ expression that converts a value to another value type (in this case a string to an integer) and then add converted values to a list.

The problem is that it shows this error:

`Range Variable 'newValue' hides a variable in an enclosing block or a range variable previously defined in the query expression`

It's complaining because newValue is defined outside of the LINQ expression but I need it there else everything shows up in red as undefined.

How can I fix this?

```
Dim newValue As Integer

Dim newList As List(Of Integer) = (
        From value In valueList
        Where Integer.TryParse(value, newValue)
        Select newValue).ToList()
```

[image]

Comment: you declared `Dim newValue As Integer` above you're trying to use it as the (assumed I work in C#) out parameter for try parse,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VB has some funny ideas about LINQ query syntax.

You can switch to lambda syntax or put parentheses around the variable in the `Select`:

```
Dim newList = valueList.Where(Function(value) Integer.TryParse(value, newValue)).Select(Function(value) newValue).ToList()

Dim newList As List(Of Integer) = (
        From value In valueList
        Where Integer.TryParse(value, newValue)
        Select (newValue)).ToList()
```

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea putting parameters around a variable works like that.